# make php regex rule in one foreach

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I have one page, there would be have some regex work. cause the regex rule would be added or removed in the future. I'd like to write them into an out file. cause the here regex rule is very long, in my way i wrote there into a json data, but the `php variable` is un-worked. Is there anyone could give me some good way for a work solution? Thanks.

json.txt

```
$json=<<<'EOT'
[
    {
        "a": "!preg_match('@www\\.aaa\\.com@',$url,$match)&&!preg_match('@www\\.bbb\\.com@',$url,$match)&&!preg_match('@www\\.ccc\\.com@',$url,$match)",
        "b": "1"
    },
    {
        "a": "!preg_match('@www\\.ddd\\.com@',$url,$match)&&!preg_match('@www\\.eee\\.com@',$url,$match)",
        "b": "2"
    },
    {
        "a": "!preg_match('@www\\.fff\\.com@',$url,$match)",
        "b": "3"
    }
]
EOT;
```

main.php

```
include("json.txt");
$date = json_decode($json);
foreach($date as $row){
    if($row->a){// i'd like to make some judge like if(!preg_match('@www\\.fff\\.com@',$url,$match)), but now the $url make non-sence, un-worked `php variable`
       echo $row->b.'<hr />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Store just the regular expression in the file, not strings of PHP code.

Comment: nickb is the solution...

Comment: @nickb, excuse me, translate into my country language, i still do not know quite well, can you give some worked code? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the `eval` method (see documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
if(eval("return $row->a;")){
```

But as the documentation says, it is a dangerous method if someone else than you can edit your json.txt file. So be sure than only authorized person can modify the content of `$row->a` before trying this solution.